# How to use multiple colors in gt_plt_bar()?

Tags: r, gt

I've just started using the `gtExtras` package and I'm wondering if there is a way to use multiple colors in `gt_plt_bar()`. I'd like each row of data in the table to be represented by a different color, but my code (below) currrently returns this error:

> **Error in dots[[2L]][[1L]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable In addition: Warning message: In if (color ==
> length(all_vals)) { :   the condition has length > 1 and only the
> first element will be used**

Is there a workaround for this?

```
remotes::install_github("jthomasmock/gtExtras")

library(gt)
library(gtExtras)

ex <- data.frame(
  a = c(9.1, 11.8, 0.9, 5.6, 2.5, 1.7, 1.4, 2.4, 5.1, 8.2, 6.6, 4.4, 2.7, 2.3,
        2.2, 6.7)
  )

a_colors <- c("#97233f", "#241773", "#0b162a", "#fb4f14", "#002244",
            "#002244", "#203731", "#000000", "#002244", "#008e97",
            "#4f2683", "#203731", "#004953", "#000000", "#002244",
            "#aa0000")

ex %>%
  gt() %>%
  gt_plt_bar(column = a, keep_column = TRUE, color = a_colors)
```

Comment: Thanks, @akrun. I had that error previously, too. I believe I was able to fix that by updating my `gtExtras` and `ggplot2` versions.

Comment: I did the same and got rid of that issue.  Thanks.  I guess the current issue is that it takes only a single `color` as parameter.  I was thinking that you may need to loop over the rows, create the gt_plt_bar individually, but I couldn't find a merge function for multiplel objects.  Can you post this as an issue/feature request in the github page for the package